# Creating QGIS processing script parameter with multiple Rasters

Tags: raster, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to create a QGIS script that would use multiple Raster layers as an input parameter. But `QgsProcessingParameterRasterLayer` only gives a single Raster as input and `QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers` defaults to a multiselect of Vector layers.

I'm probably missing something easy, but how can I get the multiselect to work with raster files like the Merge Rasters tool does for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the [QgsProcessing.SourceType](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessing.html#acad4d2322342455b53eee5701e2b3115) to the `QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers` [class constructor](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers.html#a51dd6c5a0c3aab1badc3187ad6adb85b):

```py
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr("Input rasters"),
        QgsProcessing.TypeRaster))
```