# PyQGIS error - 'QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers' is not defined

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

I'm making my first tool script in QGIS LTR (3.22.8). I'm following the answer given [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/413920/creating-qgis-processing-script-parameter-with-multiple-rasters) about multiple layer parameters. I'm using the following code:

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr('Input layers'),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
    )
)
```

I get this error:

> ScriptEditorDialog.py", line 253, in runAlgorithm
> alg.initAlgorithm()
> File "", line 105, in initAlgorithm
> NameError: name 'QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers' is not defined

Why is this? I'm using the Python template, and the method  `QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers` appears in the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import it first:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProcessingParameterMultipleLayers
```